# Mysql query to sum column based on different month criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields

Suf_id | Category | Subcategory | Collection | Vendor | quantity_sold | sales | month | year

I want to sum the quantity_sold and sales column for the last 1 month, last 3 month, and last 12 month based on the selected year duration in a single mysql query.

I have tried the following query.

```
SELECT `category`, `subcategory`, `collection`, `vendor_id`, 
   (SELECT SUM(quantity_sold) 
      FROM `sales_upload_file` as s2 
      where file_month = 5 
          and file_year = 2017 
          and s2.`category` = s1.category 
          and s2.`subcategory` = s1.subcategory 
          and s2.`collection` = s1.collection 
          and s2. `vendor_id` = s1.vendor_id) as month_1_sold, 
   (SELECT SUM(sales) 
      FROM `sales_upload_file` as s2 
      where file_month = 5 
         and file_year = 2017 
         and s2.`category` = s1.category 
         and s2.`subcategory` = s1.subcategory 
         and s2.`collection` = s1.collection 
         and s2. `vendor_id` = s1.vendor_id) as month_1_sale, 
   (SELECT SUM(quantity_sold) 
      FROM `sales_upload_file` as s2 
      where file_month <= 5 
         and file_month >= 3 
         and file_year = 2017 
         and s2.`category` = s1.category 
         and s2.`subcategory` = s1.subcategory 
         and s2.`collection` = s1.collection 
         and s2. `vendor_id` = s1.vendor_id) as month_3_sold, 
   (SELECT SUM(sales) 
       FROM `sales_upload_file` as s2 
       where file_month <= 5 
         and file_month >= 3 
         and file_year = 2017 
         and s2.`category` = s1.category 
         and s2.`subcategory` = s1.subcategory 
         and s2.`collection` = s1.collection 
         and s2. `vendor_id` = s1.vendor_id) as month_3_sale, 
   (SELECT SUM(quantity_sold) 
      FROM `sales_upload_file` as s2 
      where file_month <= 5 
         and file_month >= 1 
         and file_year = 2017 
         and s2.`category` = s1.category 
         and s2.`subcategory` = s1.subcategory 
         and s2.`collection` = s1.collection 
         and s2. `vendor_id` = s1.vendor_id 
UNION 

SELECT SUM(quantity_sold) 
   FROM `sales_upload_file` as s2 
   where file_month >= 6 
      and file_month <= 12 
      and file_year = 2016 
      and s2.`category` = s1.category 
      and s2.`subcategory` = s1.subcategory 
      and s2.`collection` = s1.collection 
      and s2. `vendor_id` = s1.vendor_id) as month_12_sold, 
   (SELECT SUM(sales) 
      FROM `sales_upload_file` as s2 
      where file_month <= 5 
         and file_month >= 1 
         and file_year = 2017 
         and s2.`category` = s1.category 
         and s2.`subcategory` = s1.subcategory 
         and s2.`collection` = s1.collection 
         and s2. `vendor_id` = s1.vendor_id 
UNION 

SELECT SUM(sales) 
   FROM `sales_upload_file` as s2 
   where file_month >= 6 
      and file_month <= 12 
      and file_year = 2016 
      and s2.`category` = s1.category 
      and s2.`subcategory` = s1.subcategory 
      and s2.`collection` = s1.collection 
      and s2. `vendor_id` = s1.vendor_id) as month_12_sale 

   FROM `sales_upload_file` as `s1` 
   WHERE `processed` = '1' 
      AND `pc` = '1' GROUP BY `category`, `subcategory`, `collection`, `vendor_id` ORDER BY `category`, `subcategory`, `collection`, `vendor_id`
```

I am getting an error subquery return more than 1 row

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated my post. Please refresh to see what I have tried.

Comment: Sorry we asked. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I will just sit here, till the pending edit is reviewed so I reformat this querry! I have a natural desire to make sense of this world.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your query this way (I couldn't do any test since you didn't post create script and sample data: pls post them to have more help):

```
    SELECT s1.category
        ,s1.subcategory
        ,s1.COLLECTION
        ,s1.vendor_id
        , SUM(s2.quantity_sold) AS month_1_sold
        , SUM(s2.sales) AS month_1_sale
        , SUM(s3.quantity_sold) AS month_3_sold
        , SUM(s3.sales) AS month_3_sale
        , SUM(s4.quantity_sold) AS month_12_sold
        , SUM(s4.sales) AS month_12_sale
    FROM sales_upload_file s1
    LEFT JOIN sales_upload_file s2 ON s2.category = s1.category
    AND s2.subcategory = s1.subcategory
    AND s2.COLLECTION = s1.COLLECTION
    AND s2.vendor_id = s1.vendor_id
        AND s2.file_year = 2017 AND s2.file_month = 5
    LEFT JOIN sales_upload_file s3 ON s3.category = s1.category
                AND s3.subcategory = s1.subcategory
                AND s3.COLLECTION = s1.COLLECTION
                AND s3.vendor_id = s1.vendor_id
                AND s3.file_year = 2017 AND s3.file_month >= 3 AND s3.file_month<=5
    LEFT JOIN sales_upload_file s4 ON s4.category = s1.category
                AND s4.subcategory = s1.subcategory
                AND s4.COLLECTION = s1.COLLECTION
                AND s4.vendor_id = s1.vendor_id
                AND ((s4.file_year = 2017 AND s4.file_month >= 1 AND s4.file_month<=5) OR (s4.file_year = 2016 AND s4.file_month >= 6 AND s4.file_month<=12))
    WHERE s1.processed = '1'
                AND s1.pc = '1'
    GROUP BY s1.category
                ,s1.subcategory
                ,s1.COLLECTION
                ,s1.vendor_id
    ORDER BY s1.category
                ,s1.subcategory
                ,s1.COLLECTION
                ,s1.vendor_id
```